# Why Does a Remote Desktop Connection Log Me Off?

Tags: windows, mac, remote-desktop

When I connect to my Windows 7 PC from my Mac using RDC, everything works fine but then almost instantly my Windows 7 PC signs off. Is there a way to disable this from happening? Or is this normal with RDC? I just started using it today. I set it up by allowing my account, Blaenk, to connect. To connect I must login as when I login when I'm at my computer, and everything works fine. It's just that my PC logs off as soon as I RDC in. Thanks, I appreciate any help.

Comment: For the record: You are *not* logged out but rather your interactive console session gets *locked*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal for RDC. It doesn't allow 2 people to view and control the desktop at the same time.

For that there are many alternatives:

- [Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com/index.aspx)
- [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/)
- [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/)

Comment: Thanks. I actually game from VNC, a friend told me that for windows, RDC seemed to be better. From my preliminary tests it did seem true. I think I can live with it logging off the other computer. RDC definitely seems a bit snappier and I like how it's native to the operating system. I will keep VNC for other systems.

Comment: I meant to say "I came from VNC", not game, haha, that would lag badly.

Answer (score 2):

This is, to my knowledge, how RDC works. If you want to keep your W7 PC logged in when using itfrom the mac i suugest you get VNC or a similar product.